# Why is a branch not shown by git branch?

Tags: git

In Windows 10's cmd

```
>git branch
* master
```

There is only one branch shown, which is the master branch.
I was told that there is another branch named "staging", but I didn't see it.

When I run the following command

```
>git checkout staging
Branch staging set up to track remote branch staging from origin.
Switched to a new branch 'staging'
```

Then

```
>git branch
* master
  staging
```

Why is the staging branch not shown at first and then shown now?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you created this branch? If not, use `git checkout -b staging`

Comment: I didn't. I cloned a remote repo by running a batch file of others.

Answer (score 2):

git only lists local branches until you checkout a remote branch.

```
git branch -r
```

will list all remote branches also

Comment: Thanks. At the beginning, I ran some batch file which cloned the remote repository. My local repo doesn't have the staging branch, and is it because the clone operation didn't pull the staging branch, but only the master branch?

Answer (score 2):

Note that Git said:

> Switched to a *new* branch 'staging'

(emphasis mine).  The branch `staging` *did not exist* until you asked Git to check it out.  Git tried to check it out, which failed—so then it tried to *create* it, and *that* worked.  This is a special operation built in to `git checkout`: if you ask to check out a branch by name, and the name does not correspond to any existing branch, Git will see if there's one so-called *remote-tracking branch* with a "close enough" name.

To list these remote-tracking branches, use:

```
git branch --list --remotes
```

or abbreviate this as `git branch -lr`.  If you have `origin/zerblatt`, you can create your own `zerblatt` by running `git checkout zerblatt`.  If you don't have that, `git checkout` will just complain that `zerblatt` is not a branch or a path that it understands.

---

In a comment, you asked:

> is [this] because the clone operation didn't pull the staging branch, but only the master branch?

Watch out for Git's peculiar terminology: you don't "pull" a branch by cloning.  The word `pull` means the `git pull` command, which I suggest you avoid: it's meant as a convenience shortcut, but it will do things you won't want it to.

The `clone` command clones *everything* by default, but it makes, for you, your own private repository, separate from the other Git repository.  That *other* Git repository has its own branches, which are now different from your branches.  To keep them separate for you, your Git *renames* all their branches: their `master` becomes your `origin/master`, and their `staging` becomes your `origin/staging`.

These `origin/*` names are (your, not their) *remote-tracking branches*, and correspond to their (regular or *local*) branches.  Your own local branches are *yours* to do with as you like, but initially, Git just creates one, normally `master`.

The really tricky thing here is what a branch actually means and is.  You may wish to read [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452) (save this for later, if you're very new to Git).  There are several different things that Git uses that are all loosely called "branch"; and while they are all related, they are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

When cloning a repository, only one "normal" (local) branch is created in the cloned repository (in your case `master`). The other branches of the source repository are stored as "remote" branches in the cloned repository. You can see them by adding the `-r` (lists *only* remote branches), or `-a` (lists local *and* remote branches) option to `git branch`.

In your case, it might have looked like this

```
> git branch -a
* master
  origin/master
  origin/staging
```

To create a new local branch which points to the same commit as `origin/staging`, run

```
> git branch staging origin/staging
```

or, to check that new branch out at the same time:

```
> git checkout -b staging origin/staging
```

---

As shown in [torek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42116929), explicitly naming `origin/stagin` is optional.

Quoting the [`git-checkout` manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

> ***git checkout* <branch>**
>
> […]
>
> If <branch> is not found but there does exist a tracking branch in exactly one remote (call it <remote>) with a matching name, treat as
>   equivalent to
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b <branch> --track <remote>/<branch>
> ```

This has the advantage of automatically setting up the new local branch to track the remote branch.